# Rhino JS, error in declaration?

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I'm trying to use [CSSParser](http://cssparser.sourceforge.net/) (0.9.5) from Rhino.  The documentation seems to be lacking, but I found [this sample code](http://cssparser.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cssparser/cssparser/src/test/java/com/steadystate/css/TestDOM.java?revision=1.2&view=markup) that makes sense to me.

But when I try, with Rhino 1.7R2:

```
js> var is = new java.io.FileInputStream("style.css");
js> var r = new java.io.InputStreamReader(is);
js> var source = new Packages.org.w3c.css.sac.InputSource(r);
js> var parser = new Packages.com.steadystate.css.parser.CSSOMParser();
js> parser
com.steadystate.css.parser.CSSOMParser@d24e3f
js> parser.parseStyleDeclaration
function parseStyleDeclaration() {/*
org.w3c.dom.css.CSSStyleDeclaration parseStyleDeclaration(org.w3c.css.sac.InputSource)
void parseStyleDeclaration(org.w3c.dom.css.CSSStyleDeclaration,org.w3c.css.sac.InputSource)
*/}

js> parser.parseStyleDeclaration(source);
null [1:4] Error in declaration. Invalid token ".". Was expecting one of: <S>, ":".
```

Since there's 2 ways to call parseStyleDeclaration, I also tried the other one:

(same as above, but then)

```
js> var style = new Packages.com.steadystate.css.dom.CSSStyleDeclarationImpl();
js> parser.parseStyleDeclaration(style, source);
null [1:4] Error in declaration. Invalid token ".". Was expecting one of: <S>, ":".
```

It's probably something simple I'm forgetting.  But what?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I'm an idiot.

It's a CSSParser error, not a Rhino error.